# How to dynamically inject values to forms in templates?

Tags: django

I'm trying to build a comment system in Django similar to one on Reddit, where users can reply to other comments. For every comment, I create a separate reply form:

```
{% for comment in comments.all %}
    {# Displaying the coment here #}
    <form action="." method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ comment_form.as_p }}
        <p><input type="submit" value="Comment"></p>
    </form>
{% endfor %}
```

How would I go about injecting a corresponding comment's ID into each form? Is there maybe a way to specify `initial` values on a template level?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass comment id in your post method.

```
{% for comment in comments.all %}
    {# Displaying the coment here #}
    <form action="{% url 'comment_view' comment.id %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ comment_form.as_p }}
    <p><input type="submit" value="Comment"></p>
    </form>
{% endfor %}
```

urls.py

```
path('comment-view/<int:id>', views.comment_view, name="comment_view")
```

views.py

```
def comment_view(request, id):
    print('Comment id is ', id)
    return render(request, 'your-template' }
```

Comment: The view does not even render the template at all?

Comment: Thanks for it and will update. But I want to show how it works.

Comment: @SadojRai I thought it was about passing context to template, not specifying extra parameters to view url resolution. My apologies.